# What is the difference between << and +=?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have been playing around with arrays a bit, and found myself in trouble understanding the following code:

```
first_array = []
second_array = []
third_array = []                         # I initialized 3 empty arrays

third_array << [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]       # I loaded 1..9 into third_array[0]
puts third_array.size                    # => 1

first_array << third_array               # 1..9 was loaded into first_array[0]

second_array += third_array              # 1..9 was loaded into second_array[0]

puts first_array == third_array          # false
puts second_array == third_array         # true
puts first_array == second_array         # false

puts first_array.size                    # 1
puts second_array.size                   # 1
puts third_array.size                    # 1
```

What happened with this?

```
second_array += third_array              # I have no clue
```

Why aren't all the arrays equal to each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They exhibit fairly different behaviors. One creates and assigns a new `Array` object, the other modifies an existing object.

`+=` would be the same as `second_array = second_array + third_array`. This sends the `+` message to the `second_array` object passing `third_array` as the argument.

Per the documentation [`Array.+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) returns a new array object built by concatenating the two arrays. This will return a new object.

[`Array.<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) simply push the parameter to the end of the existing array object:

```
second_array = []
second_array.object_id = 1234

second_array += [1,2,3,4]
second_array.object_id = 5678

second_array << 5
second_array.object_id = 5678
```

There is also a difference in how the parameter is added. By adding other elements, it will help see why your arrays are not equal:

```
second_array = [1, 2, 3]

# This will push the entire object, in this case an array
second_array << [1,2]
# => [1, 2, 3, [1,2]]

# Specifically appends the individual elements,
# not the entire array object
second_array + [4, 5]
# => [1, 2, 3, [1,2], 4, 5]
```

This is because `Array.+` uses concatenation instead of pushing. Unlike [`Array.concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) which modifies the existing object, `Array.+` returns a new object.

You can think of a Ruby implementation like:

```
class Array
  def +(other_arr)
    dup.concat(other_arr)
  end
end
```

In your specific example, your objects look like this at the end:

```
first_array  = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]] # [] << [] << (1..9).to_a
second_array =  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]  # [] + ([] << (1..9).to_a)
third_array  =  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]  # [] << (1..9).to_a
```

Comment: So your point is that for second_array a new array is created which is not equal to the third_array even if the content of the two arrays are identical?

Comment: THAT @codedad is still not answered! has anyone an understanding of this?

Comment: second_array does equal the third_array (but it created a new object) the original example shows this. the first_array is not equal to either

Answer (score 3):

`<<` appends an item to an array

`+=` adds an array to an array.

Examples:

`[1,2] << 3` # returns [1,2,3]

`[1,2] += [3,4]` # returns [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Your example for `<<` would be better if you showed that `[1,2] << [3,4]` produced `[1,2,[3,4]]` IMHO.

Comment: @squiguy you are right. and Teddy, You mean, that in my example first_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and second_array = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]? is this correct?

Comment: @rubybrah no. `third_array` is `[[1..9]]`, `first_array` is `[[[1..9]]]` and `second_array` is `[[1..9]]`

Comment: No `first_array` is `[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]`

Answer (score 3):

The last difference not mentioned so far between `<<` and `+=` is, that `<<` is a method:

```
class Array
  def << other
    # performs self.push( other )
  end
end
```

whereas `+=` is syntax:

```
a += b
```

and is merely a shorthand for writing:

```
a = a + b
```

So, in order to modify `+=` behavior, one has to modify the `+` method:

```
class Array
  def + other
    # ....
  end
end
```