# What is the difference between #concat and += on Arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

I want to concatenate two Arrays in Ruby. So far I have found the `#concat` and the `+=` operator. They seem to produce the same result, but I want to know what is the difference between them.

- Where can I find the documentation for the `+=` operator?
- What are the differences between `#concat` and using the `+=` operator on Arrays?

Comment: Please search SO,,, lots of time it has been asked.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I doubt its the same question as the one you suggested as duplicate, the questions are not same even though the provided answers might be similar

Comment: I think this answer also has a good information on the subject:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16428467/810606.

Comment: @bjhaid Yes.. that Question was also explained the *speed*. But enough also to know the difference between them.. Isn't it ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit the questions are not similar, there is a difference between asking if one is faster than the other and what the difference between one and the other

Comment: @bjhaid If so.. I am taking it back.. There is no point to pollute SO with dup questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+=` would create a new array object, `concat` mutates the original object

```
a = [1,2]
a.object_id # => 19388760 
a += [1]
a.object_id # => 18971360 


b = [1,2]
b.object_id # => 18937180 
b.concat [1]
b.object_id # => 18937180
```

Note the `object_id` for `a` changed while for `b` did not change